# Cmder and SSH - Keep previous shell activity content after quitting full-screen process (e.g. less, vim)

Tags: ssh, shell, conemu, cmder

I want the shell activity content (e.g. the output of `ls`, `whoami`) to be shown on the terminal screen after running and quitting a full-screen process (e.g. `less`, `vim`).
They are all removed/cleared when I use *cmder* with `ssh` connecting to Ubuntu 18.04.
But they are shown as expected on:

- *Putty* with `ssh` connection
- *cmder* without `ssh` connection
- *cmder* with `ssh` connection then run `screen` having `altscreen on`

My question is similar to these posted questions:
[keep-conemu-screen-buffer-after-exiting-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502261/keep-conemu-screen-buffer-after-exiting-vim),
[conemu-ssh-clears-console-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207673/conemu-ssh-clears-console-history)
But those solutions of `export TERM=xterm` or `export TERM=cygwin` didn't work on my setup. So I wonder what could cause my setup of "*cmder* with `ssh`" to clear the terminal screen.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is caused by the *conemu* console buffer. After turning **off** the **BufferHeight** setting, the shell activity would not be removed when quitting a full-screen process on "*cmder* with ssh".

[image: Turn off buffer height]

However, this setting will disable the activity buffer for screen scrolling, which can be another problem.